# How to set FallbackResource by length of URL in .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I want to set my FallbackResource url by the length of the url
for example if the url is 10 chars long then the FallbackResource will be

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

else it will be

```
FallbackResource /other.php
```

how can I do that?

Comment: _Why_ would you want to do that? This is a decision you could easily make _in_ PHP, so what do you actually need two completely separate script files for here …?

Answer (score 0):

`FallbackResource` can be only one and is unconditional. For conditional presentation of a fall back resource it is better to use `mod_rewrite` rules but things will appear a bit complicated. Here is an example of such rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# for URIs length >= 10
RewriteRule ^.{10} index.php [L]

# for all other URIs
RewriteRule ^ other.php [L]
```